# Is Inositol chiral or achiral?

Tags: chirality

I thought Inositol was clearly chiral since it has 6 asymmetric C atoms. But friends of me argue that it is achiral and i've found websites say the same (http://bip.cnrs-mrs.fr/bip10/Inositol-EJB.pdf). So what am I missing? Is it chiral or achiral?

Comment: Suppose all atoms have the same configuration. Then each atom has two identical substituents; then how are they asymmetric?

Comment: Look here for the chirality of the inositols: http://ursula.chem.yale.edu/~chem220/chem220js/STUDYAIDS/isomers/RS14272/inositol.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Having asymmetric carbon atoms does not in itself make a compound chiral.

A compound is chiral if and only if it is not super(im)posable on its mirror image.

If there's a plane of symmetry, then reflecting in that plane gives the same thing, by definition, and that meets the criterion for super(im)posability - the mirror image is superimposable on the original and therefore the molecule is not chiral.

Only [D- and L- chiro-inositol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inositol) are chiral - all the other stereoisomers have planes of symmetry and are therefore not chiral.